# Spring GeoSpatial for Jpa Relational Databases

Tags: java, spring, geolocation, spring-data-jpa

is there a way to implement or a framework to support GeoSpatial queries in Spring?
Spring actually support it for mongodb. How can i do the same with another relational DB?

[Spring Mongo Geo Spatial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.0.M1/reference/html/#mongo.geospatial)

Comment: You mean, are there any JPA providers that support persistence of Geospatial types in RDBMS? Yes.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thats what i mean.

Comment: DataNucleus JPA and Hibernate both support differing Geospatial types. Maybe EclipseLink does also. Read the docs for the JPA provider you use. This site isn't the place to recommend one over another.